# ALC4080 Codec mic detection problems in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: sound, 22.04, microphone

I recently built a PC and dual booted Ubuntu and windows. To hear the audio coming out of my PC I use a headset that includes a mic. It has the two connectors that you plug into your computer one for mic and one for the headset. When I plug everything in on windows it operates 100% fine, but when I switch to Ubuntu it outputs audio to the headset but the mic does not work. I eventually realized that the audio out from the computer is being fed into the mic in line. When I go on discord and play a song they can hear the song, but not me. In addition the mic does not pick up any sound at all. I looked extensively online and could not find any solutions for this. I have the Realtek® ALC4080 Codec on my motherboard and I am going to include screenshots from some basic programs I found online that are helpful for debugging I believe.

http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=4f1d05edf43e99407535d4dc69d38c087ac41f77

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cz5To.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZl7C.png)

I tried to reinstall drivers and I looked for the driver on https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/sound/hd-audio/models.html however I did not see it.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/alsa-project/alsa-ucm-conf

try this

```
curl -L -o alsa-ucm-conf.tar.gz https://github.com/alsa-project/alsa-ucm-conf/archive/refs/heads/master.tar.gz

tar xvzf alsa-ucm-conf.tar.gz -C /usr/share/alsa --strip-components=1 --wildcards "*/ucm" "*/ucm2"
```

Comment: worked for me on 23.04!